# My module not displaying header and footer

Tags: magento2, module, third-party-module

This is my module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Rk_Wallet" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

This is my registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Rk_Wallet',
    __DIR__
);
```

This is my routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="wallet" frontName="rk">
            <module name="Rk_Wallet" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

This is my controller file

```
<?php
namespace Rk\Wallet\Controller\Wallet;

class Wallet extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
  public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context)
  {
    return parent::__construct($context);
  }

  public function execute()
  {
    $this->_view->loadLayout();
    $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
    $this->_view->renderLayout();
  }
}
```

Comment: not displaying in header and footer means ?

Comment: Nothing here suggests that anything should be displayed in the header or footer.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just need to display header and footer on the new empty page